# PHP: Remove nested arrays with only 1 key

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have the following array:-

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["A"]=>
    float(5)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["A"]=>
    float(1)
    ["B"]=>
    float(3)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["A"]=>
    float(5)
    ["B"]=>
    float(6)
  }
}
```

And I would like to remove/filter out the nested arrays that only store 1 key so it would end up like this:-

```
array(2) {
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["A"]=>
    float(1)
    ["B"]=>
    float(3)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["A"]=>
    float(5)
    ["B"]=>
    float(6)
  }
}
```

Is there an easy solution/way to do this?

Comment: `array_filter` in combination with `count`…

Comment: Yes, there is an easy solution/way to do this. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I used array_filter with the specific keys (["A"]) to check if they are empty and remove them, but I thought this wouldn't be ideal as there could also be a key "C" and I would need to make all of the filters manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do with simple `foreach()`:-

```
foreach($array as $key=>$arr){
   if(count($arr) == 1){
      unset($array[$key]);
   }
}

print_r($array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/832446

Or using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):-

```
$newarray = array_filter($array, function($var) {
    return (count($var) !=1);
});
```

Output:-https://eval.in/832451

Answer (score 1):

The most trivial method I could think of for this activity is to use the count function of `PHP`.

Lets assume your array as you have defined and lets call it $originalArray-

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["A"]=>
    float(5)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["A"]=>
    float(1)
    ["B"]=>
    float(3)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["A"]=>
    float(5)
    ["B"]=>
    float(6)
  }
}
```

Now we will iterate through the entire array to find indexes with multiple keys and push them onto a different array.

```
$new_array = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($originalArray);$i++)
{
   if(count($originalArray[$i])>1)
   {
     array_push($new_array,$originalArray[$i]);
   }
}
```